# How to handle Serialization error in Spring cloud stream kafka streams binder?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am writing a Kafka streams application using Spring cloud stream kafka streams binder.

While the consumer publishes message to a output topic, there may be an error like **Serialization error** or **Network error**.

In this code -

```java
@Bean
public Function<KStream<Object, String>, KStream<Object, String>> process() {
    return (input) -> {
        KStream<Object, String> kt = input.flatMapValues(v -> Arrays.asList(v.toUpperCase().split("\\W+")));
        return kt;
    };
}
```

Here while producing the message back to the output topic if an error occurs, how to handle it. Is there any mechanism in Kafka streams binder other than **RetryTemplate** ?

Comment: @sobychacko can you please help?

Comment: Hi, there maybe a few options to get around that in the binder. You can try using `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer` and provide various hooks to handle producer exceptions. See this blog: https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/06/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-5-application-customizations

Answer (score 1):

See [the Spring for Apache Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer).

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the poll() returns. To solve this problem, version 2.2 introduced the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 returns a null value and a DeserializationException in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level MessageListener, if the ConsumerRecord contains a DeserializationException header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.